# Using WPF & C#, how to show uploaded files as Hyperlinks with a delete button for each file

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Using WPF  & C#, how to show uploaded files as Hyperlinks, giving a delete button for each file, so that we can delete one file at a time if not required. I am able to show the files as mere text in the textbox. How to proceed further. Can anybody help me please.??

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please post the code and the problems you have with it.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are going to need to enumerate the files so start with `IEnumerable<string> System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(string path)`.

This of course will need to be exposed to the View so that you can create the UI for each item. This is done as a list

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfFiles}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
```

To create a hyperlink you simply use a hyperlink inside a textblock such as

```
 <TextBlock>
   <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Text="{Binding}" />
 </TextBlock>
```

You will notice that I'm binding to a DeleteCommand which expects to have a pararmeter passed to it, that parameter is the same as the text displayed in the link. I'd choose this over trying to do it with a `Clicked` since you get the filename.

How you implement the `Command` is up to you and whether there is a default Command implementation in whichever MVVM framework you want to use. If you aren't using one then you can use the RelayCommand from [Josh Smith's original MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

```
   RelayCommand _deleteCommand;
    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_deleteCommand == null)
            {
                _deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(
                     param => this.Delete(param), 
                     param => this.CanDelete(param));
            }
            return _deleteCommand;
        }
    }
```

You then only need to provide implementations for `bool CanDelete(sting filename)` which maps directly to `System.IO.File.Exists(filename)` and for `void Delete(string filename)` which maps to `System.IO.File.Delete(filename)`.